# SingPath and Python Help! - Infinite loop error in "Create a Problemset Mode"

Tags: python, python-3.x

SingPath is an interactive problem set website that tracks your progression within multiple programming languages. Unfortunately it has some bugs. The largest is the error:

> Your code took too long to return. Your solution may be stuck in an infinite loop. Please try again.

appearing multiple times when you run your problem set code. Now all you have to do to correct the bug while answering a problem set question is to just rerun the code.

**However**, within the problem creator it creates a HUGE issue. Essentially you can run the code until it works in the creator as well which is not the problem for testing. The issue stems from submitting the `problem/solution` due to the fact that the submit button reruns the code. This means you need to get two consecutive correct answers which are near impossible to get (I've been trying for an hour now). The fact that *creating* a problem is required to continue within the problem set is quite ruined on the buggy creator.

So (finally) here's my question, How can I make the following code run without this error in the creator?

Code:

```
import string
import random

# Takes a blank string then replaces it with 3 random letters/numbers.

def string3(s1):    
    s2 = ''
    def randstring (size = 3, chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
       a = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
       return a

    ''' If the string brought in isnot equal to the string generated keep
        rerunning the random string generator '''

    while s1 != s2:    
        s2 = randstring()

    return 'True'
```

---

Sample function calls:

```
>>> string3('abc')
'True'
>>> string3('a2d')
'True'
>>> string3('234')
'True'
```

What the code does:

The Infinite Monkey Theorem states that

> Given enough time, a hypothetical monkey typing at random would, as part of its output, almost surely produce all of Shakespeare's plays.

Create a function `string3` that would randomly generate strings of 3 characters until those character's are equal to the string received from the function. Hint: Search for a random string generator for reference. All characters in a string will be lower case.

I am a beginner programmer and I would like if some comments were put it so I can understand more complicated solutions although I would be grateful for any help/suggestions!

Also, I have already notified the support staff at SingPath for the bug but I would like to get as much practice in today as I can! If it's impossible to potentially fix the bug on the client side I completely understand! Best of luck!

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

I forgot to mention that this bug will happen regardless of loops within the code. While my program is very intense with the constant random assignment of characters I know it isn't the issue (it might be AN issue but not THE issue XD). If you don't believe me try to create a problem here: http://singpath.appspot.com/

Even a simple function declaration and return such as:

```
def add_one(n):
       return n+1
```

Can cause the loop bug! If I can do anything on my side (exception statement?) Please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code may be slow, but you're going to see that error no matter what you do.  I just logged in there and started my way down the Python path and got the same error with the not-very-computationally intensive:

```
oops=317
```

What appears to be happening to that site is that it's being slammed by too much traffic.  (Back in the day, I'd say they were being slash-dotted, but I guess it'd be more correct to say they're being stackoverflowed. ;)

Comment: Absolutely John (You answered one of my questions the other day and I thank you for that). Do you think there is anything that could be done to manually access the serverside ran code? Like finding what the exception is called and using an exception statement to catch the error or am I going to have to find another website to practice my python knowledge until they work out a solution? Thanks for your input! - Winkleson

Comment: Go to the SO [Python Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) page, and scroll down to the free python books section.  Lots of good links there, personally I've used the official tutorial, dive into python and thinking in python.

Comment: Thankyou so much John for your dedication to programmers :D You go above and beyond most people. I'll be sure to look into it!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug or an error, it is a design decision. What you are doing is VERY computationally intensive (see below for an explanation), and the website probably has a limited hardware budget. If they allowed each student to run buggy infinite code for as much as they wanted the business would go down in flames very quickly. So they decided you code should be killed.

There are 27^n possible n-character words composed of the 27 lowercase characters of the (English) Latin alphabet. That is a large number of things to be trying, even when n is only 3. Moreover, you are generating string at random, so inevitably some would be repeated and you may have to generate much more than 27^n strings to find the one you are looking for.

This is an important lesson- it is very easy to white something which takes year to complete.

Comment: Actually... this bug will run even if you do not contain any form of loop within the code although I do see where you are coming from. If I even ran a function it wouldn't work :P Check it out for yourself! http://singpath.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

From the original question (posted as an answer):

> After multiple attempts of letting the program run and then submitting I finally got lucky and it submitted my problem "Sir Monkey Shakespeare". Crappy name for a problem I know but it finally got the job done. If you are having the same bug try to remove any private tests as it will provide correct answers almost every time due to the lack of having to run the code again.